# Javascript array issue with HTML radio boxes

Tags: javascript

I have a basic JS question about arrays.

I just can't seem to wrap my brain around the following code. I understand that you need the following code in order for the program to understand that its checked, but can someone please walk me though the JS line by line?...

```js
 var sex = document.getElementsByName("sex");
  var sex_value = "";
        //here is where my confusion starts 
  for (var i=0; i < sex.length; i++)
  {
   if (sex[i].checked)
    sex_value = sex[i].value;
  }
       // where my confusion ends 
  if(sex_value == 0)
  {
   alert("What is your sex?...");
   return false;
  }


// buttons and what not go here
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is currently, when ever the page loads, you will always see the "What is your sex?..." alert as none of the checkboxes are selected on page load. If you add `checked` to one of the radio input elements, on page load, the `sex_value` variable should contain the value of the corresponding `checked` input element.

Here's the line-commented code.

```
// Gets all elements on the page that have a name="sex"
var sex = document.getElementsByName("sex");

// Sets a blank string to be updated later (or remain blank)
var sex_value = "";

// This loop runs through all of the [name="sex"] elements
for (var i=0; i < sex.length; i++)
{
    // If the value is selected, set sex_value to the value of the input
    if (sex[i].checked)
        sex_value = sex[i].value;
}

// Really should be if( sex_value === '' )
if(sex_value == 0)
{
    alert("What is your sex?...");
    return false;
}
```

And here's an example of what happens when you set the `checked` element: http://jsfiddle.net/529kx4co/

Answer (score 0):

```
var sex = document.getElementsByName("sex");
```

Here `sex` is a collection of DOM elements having `name="sex"` defined.

And this one:

```
for (var i=0; i < sex.length; i++)
    {
        if (sex[i].checked) {
            sex_value = sex[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
```

is: for each DOM element in that collection check if element is checked. If it is so get its value property and assign it to `sex_value` variable.

That value will be the value of the whole radio group (collection of input|radio having the same name).